# Matching local javascript file to remote file for debugging in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a project in which javascript files are dynamically loaded into a page by the server using a python script.  I am trying to use visual studio to debug these javascript files by attaching to the appropriate IE process for the loaded page and using the script debugger.

The problem is that IE and Visual Studio identify the dynamically loaded scripts like this:

> scriptLoader.py?get=Utils

but Visual Studio identifies the javascript source file like this:

> Utils.js

Because of this, VS doesn't recognize these as being the same source and the only way I can debug is to cause an exception to occur so that IE opens VS and loads the copy that was served to the browser.

Is there any way to force VS to recognize that Utils.js and scriptLoader.py?get=Utils are the same source?

Comment: Is firebug + firefox an option?

Comment: The Javascript I am trying to debug works in conjunction with an IE Extension that my team is developing.  We do have a Firefox version of the extension as well, but I need to debug the script while running in IE to get it to work properly with our IE plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do what you're describing, but you can always just use this nice line:

```
debugger;
```

which will cause the debugger to load on the specified line.

Comment: Thanks jvenema.  Looks like this is the best solution for now.